# Can the browser be instructed to cache a resource with a variable query string?

Tags: tomcat, browser, nginx

Can a server (Nginx or Tomcat ideally), when it first responds to a browser request, instruct the browser to cache that resource, even if the query string changes in future requests?

Answer (score 0):

No.

Actually, HTTP does not distinguish path and parameters. Everything after server name is request string.

Even changing parameters order results in completely new request.